# imagepicker flutter cant be used

Tags: android, flutter, dart

im new in flutter and i made a project using this, i have a problem that
when i want to use imagepicker it couldn't be used i have following step by step on youtube and i getting error on

"File imageFile; says non-nullable instance field ' imageFile' must be initialized."

and on "Pickedfile.path says the propety 'path' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

[this](https://imgur.com/a/8lKbxuH) pictur that showing error

this is my writed code

```
  File imageFile;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  chooseImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final PickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: source);

    setState(() {
      imageFile = File(PickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: imageFile != null
                      ? Container(
                          height: 120.0,
                          width: 120.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                            image: FileImage(imageFile),
                          )),
                        )
                      : Container(
                          height: 120.0,
                          width: 120.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                        )),
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      chooseImage(ImageSource.gallery)
                    },
                    child: Text('Ubah Foto Profil'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Which android version you are testing on? and if possible can you tell the exact file path as well? and also given link is not working, if you can update it?

Comment: android 11, how to find file path?

Comment: you can print this value `PickedFile.path`

Comment: how? can you tell me? im new and really confuse

Comment: You can put a debugger inside `setState` method and try to see the value, or just use `print(PickedFile.path)` inside setState method

Comment: cant do that "path" showing error when i put on setState heres the pict https://imgur.com/a/oRlUAii

Comment: My bad, not inside setState, just outside of it, 

`final PickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: source);
print(PIckedFile.path.toString());
 `

Comment: cant show too many positional argument

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if it works for you.

```
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  var imageFile;
 _getFromGallery() async {
var pickedFile = (await picker.pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery,
));
if (pickedFile != null) {
  setState(() {
    imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
  });
}
}
Widget _imageSection() {
return (imageFile == null)
    ? Container(
  width:
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: 220,
  child: Card(
    elevation: 3.0,
    color: Colors.white,
    shadowColor: Colors.grey,
    // child: Image.asset(ImageUtil
    //     .PUNCH_IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER),
    child: Text("No image selected"),
  ),
)
    : Container(
  /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: 
ColorUtil.leavePageContainerBorder),
  ),*/
  width:
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: 220,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      // Text(imageFile),
      Image.file(imageFile,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
    ),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment:
              MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _getFromGallery();
                    print(imageFile);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                      'Ubah Foto Profil'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _imageSection(),
          ]),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: still showing error heres the pict that show the error [] (https://imgur.com/a/8lKbxuH)

Comment: I have edited my code. Let me know if it works

Comment: on path says the propety can't be unconditionaly accessed, what should i do?

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: i have running the app on my phone when i try to jump to this page the app immediatly showing red screen and on my IDE terminal show this [https://imgur.com/a/fKaFROZ]

Comment: I have edited my code. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: look like the getimage got deprecated on my version

Comment: Add .pickImage() instead. See my code

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are initializing file path with null give some value and than change it using setstate()

Comment: what should i change?

Comment: imageFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
          source: sourceofimage, //pass the source like gallery or camera
        );

Comment: it got error says " A value of type 'XFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.

Comment: and on 'File ImageFile; its says error non-nullable instance field 'ImageFile' must be initialized.

Comment: than try this Future getImage() async {
  var image = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {
    imageFile = File(image.path);
  });
}

Comment: write it on same place setstate?

Comment: btw when i write imagePicker.getImage is got deprecated so i change it to pickImage and got same error Instance member 'pickImage can't be accessed